# Minecraft map help 1.12

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to do command blocks for a map this kid in my class but have got stuck on a particular part. So what I am trying to do is every 20 game ticks effect them with instant damage then reset the scoreboard counter but only while they are within a 2 block radius of a Armour stand named damage-radius (that is also the scoreboard name) The problem I'm having is when 1 person is within that radius it adds to the scoreboard of all players thank you in advance here is what I have done already these are running in chain command blocks that are always active with command 2 and 4 being conditional also im pretty sure the command is in the 2nd command block

> execute @a ~ ~ ~ /testfor @e[name=damage-radius,r=5]
>
> /scoreboard players add @a damage-radius 1
>
> /effect @a[score_damage-radius=20,score_damage-radius_min=20] minecraft:instant_damage 1 1
>
> /scoreboard players set @a[score_damage-radius_min=20] damage-radius 0

Answer (score 2):

I am going to explain what your commands are actually doing.

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ /testfor @e[name=damage-radius,r=5]
```

This means execute the command `testfor @e[name=damage-radius,r=5]` from the location of all players.  This will result positive if there is an armor stand within 5 block radius of the player and run the next command.  It does nothing to target the player.  It only returns that there is an armor stand near a player.

```
/scoreboard players add @a damage-radius 1
```

This means add 1 to the damage-radius objective for **all** players.  This does not target any specific player.  This is your problem.

---

A better way to do it.  First, skip the `testfor`. Second, run the command directly by targeting the player that is near the armor stand (Backwards of your method of targeting an armor stand that is near a player)

```
execute @e[name=damage-radius] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players add @a[r=5] damage-radius 1
```

This means execute the command `scoreboard players add @a[r=5] damage-radius 1` at the location of an entity named "damage-radius."

This will add 1 to the  damage-radius objective of only the player that is near the armor stand.

Your other two commands will work as they are.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead do

```
execute @e[name=damage-radius] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players add @a[r=5] damage=radius 1
effect @a[score_damage-radius=20,score_damage-radius_min=20] minecraft:instant_damage 1 1
scoreboard players set @a[score_damage-radius_min=20] damage-radius 0
```

Even better, just use an area effect cloud:

```
summon area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Particle:take,ReapplicationDelay:20,Radius:5f,Duration:2147483647,Effects:[{Id:7,Amplifier:0,Duration:20}]}
```

Comment: than you for the help but this is for a lot of Armour stands at once so the area affect is not better suited and other way is more suited for it